# Skip json object (PHP session)

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have an array of users. Each user can be skipped on .click button. However I want it to skip the user that logs in. The session is started with PHP, but I'm showing the user through ajax and javascript. However

```
       if(sSession = sKey){
            aPeople.slice(this.jPerson);
        }
```

is not correctly skipping the user. Could you help?

Here's the code:

```
$("#btnSkip").click(function() {
$.getJSON('include/users.txt', function(aPeople){

        var getPerson = function(id) {
            var jPerson = aPeople[id]
            var sID = jPerson.id
            var sName = jPerson.name
            var sImage = jPerson.picture                
            var sSession = $('#mySession').text()
            var sKey = jPerson.key

            //this if statement doesn't work
            if(sSession == sKey){
                console.log(sSession)
                console.log(sKey)
                console.log(personIndex)
                console.log(jPerson)
                aPeople.splice(jPerson);
            }

            $('#sName').text(sName)
            $('#sImg').attr('src', sImage)

            //TO START COUNT AGAIN

            if(aPeople.length -1 == personIndex){
                personIndex = 0
            }else{
                personIndex = personIndex + 1
            }    
        }
            getPerson(personIndex);

            $( '#sName' ).fadeIn( 'slow' )
            $( '#sImg' ).fadeIn( 'slow' )
            })
        })
```

Comment: Note that one equal sign is used to assign, two to compare.

Comment: corrected to: if(sSession == sKey){
                    aPeople.slice(this.jPerson);
                }
but still not working

Comment: slice() method returns a part of array into new array, so you should assign a sliced array to a new variable, or to existing. 

aPeople =  aPeople.slice(this.jPerson);

Comment: `this.jPerson` wouldn't exist. It would just be jPerson, you aren't assigning the value to this.jPerson.

Comment: i updated the code. but still not working :(

Comment: Did you change the slice() part as @niklaz mentioned?
aPeople = aPeople.slice(jPerson);

Comment: I didn't understand the explanation. but i did removed .this element since it is generating the right person on console.log with jPerson only

Comment: array.slice() does not change the array itself, it returns a new array instead that you need to assign in a variable , so even if everything else is correct in your code, when you check against aPeople, you check a version that is not modified by slice()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks to me like to you want to:

1. Retrieve an array of user objects.
2. Navigate the retrieved list and display each user on a button click.
3. Never display the logged in user.

Here's a suggested solution:

1. I'm filtering out the logged in user with the jQuery grep function.
2. I simplified your navigation logic.
3. I wasn't sure you meant to retrieve the users JSON on every click, so I altered that also.

```js
  function setupUserNavigator(users, loggedInUserKey) {
    var idx = 0;

    // filter out the logged in user
    var filtered = $.grep(users, function(user) {
      return !(user.key === loggedInUserKey);
    });

    function current() {
      return filtered[idx];
    }

    function next() {
      idx += 1;
    }

    function more() {
      return idx < filtered.length - 1;
    }

    return { current, next, more };
  }

  function displayUser(user) {
    $('#sName').text(user.name);
    $('#sImg').attr('src', user.picture);
  }

  function usersResponseHandler(users) {
    var loggedInUserKey = $('#mySession').text();
    var userNavigator = setupUserNavigator(users, loggedInUserKey);

    // display the first user immediately
    displayUser(userNavigator.current());

    // display each subsequent user on a 'next' button click
    $('#next').click(function() {
      userNavigator.next();
      displayUser(userNavigator.current());

      if(!userNavigator.more()) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  }
  
  // $.getJSON('include/users.txt', usersResponseHandler);

  // use test data for the snippet and mock response handler call
  var data = [
    { id: '1', key: '1234', name: 'Joe', picture: 'img/joe.png' },
    { id: '2', key: '5678', name: 'John', picture: 'img/john.png' },
    { id: '3', key: '9012', name: 'Sarah', picture: 'img/sarah.png' },
    { id: '4', key: '0987', name: 'Tim', picture: 'img/tim.png' },
    { id: '5', key: '6543', name: 'Lily', picture: 'img/lily.png' }
  ];
  
  usersResponseHandler(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Logged In User Key:
<div id="mySession">9012</div><br />

Name:
<div id="sName"></div>
Picture:
<div><img id="sImg" src="" /></div><br />
<button id="next">Next</button>
```